# User Control with Public Property in FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview, webusercontrol

I have added a user control into a form view item template, but I have added a public property to the user control, and I can't seem to figure out how to set the property. I have tried the following:

```
<uc1:OfacControl id="OfacControl1" runat="server" AssetEvictionId='<%# Bind("AssetEvictionId") %>' />
```

But the value never gets set correctly.

I have also tried doing it in the codebehind of the form in the preRender method like so:

```
var assetEvictionIdHiddenField = (HiddenField)oFormView.FindControl("AssetEvictionIdHiddenField");
var OfacControl1 = (Ofac)oFormView.FindControl("OfacControl1");

if (OfacControl1 != null && assetEvictionIdHiddenField != null)
    OfacControl1.AssetEvictionId = Convert.ToInt32(assetEvictionIdHiddenField.Value);
```

This doesn't work either.

It appears to be a timing issue. It looks like the control is being rendered at a different time than the value is being set. If the bind syntax doesn't work, and I am forced to use the code behind, which form view event should I be using to set the value. I have also tried the OnItemCreated event. This didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to set the control in the wrong place.  You should be setting it in Init.

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) states the following:

> [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init.aspx)
>
> Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin settings
>   have been applied. The
>   [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init.aspx)
>   event of individual controls occurs before the
>   [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init.aspx)
>   event of the page. Use this event to read or initialize control
>   properties.